Are reflection and transmission coefficients in 1D problem are independent of the direction in which we choose as incident?
I was watching a lecture series of Quantum mechanics of Professor V. Balakrishnan,
There was a problem session,

“For an arbitrary potential barrier (any potential function of position and it need not to be symmetric or antisymmetric) If R and T are the reflection and transmission coefficients respectively when we consider a particle incident from the left side of the barrier, Now if we do the same calculations but considering the particle is incident from the right side of the potential barrier and we obtain reflection and transmission coefficients R' and T' respectively, Then is it necessary to R and R' with T and T' to be equal?”

The professor replied positively, and explained we have never used symmetry of the potential to derive expressions for R and T,
But I am having a doubt, If the potential is not having any kind of symmetry or antisymmetry, then on each side the value of the potential would be different for given x on both sides,
Then it would surely affect the wave number in the region of potential, as it would be $$k'=\sqrt{\dfrac{8π²m(E-V(x))}{h²}}$$, here as we can see if  V(x) is different on both sides then k' must be different for the particle entering the barrier from left and right, then shouldn't R & R' with T & T' be different?
Now, I guess R and R' would not change as incident from any side doesn't affect the wave numbers on both sides, this tells that T and T' must be equal as R+T=R'+T'=1, but I think for T' the calculation will be such that it would be numerically equal to T, but How and why does it happen even for a non symmetric potential barrier? And apart from this, I really want to ask are R' and T' are really equal to R and T respectively?

Link to lecture? Minute?

If V is continuous it would be the same for the same x though, I don't follow your reasoning.

https://youtu.be/3IbjiCmHbLs?si=vLTkh5EDT6jF_Poi           Time:25:40

You are right. There is some symmetry, but only enough to relate $T$ and $T'$, not to get $R=R'$.
You can even find this as a classical result: (for light or EM waves, or electrical signals) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters[Scattering parameters]1

In general the reflection and transmission coefficients are not independent of direction for arbitrary potentials. For a discussion of the conditions under which the transmission coefficient is direction independent, see Section III of Walker and Gathright's paper Exploring one‐dimensional quantum mechanics with transfer matrices, Am. J. Phys. 62, 408–422 (1994).
